# Best practice design for icon with transparency to contrast with dynamic background

Tags: user-interface, background, icons, transparent, contrast

I have an icon that stays in the bottom right corner of my web page used for switching to and from full screen mode. The icon has a transparent background so the background image can show through.
[Icon w/ transparency and good contrast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AXeV.png)
However, whenever the window resizes the background image does also and sometimes the part of the image that ends up under the icon is almost the same color/shade as the icon, so the icon gets lost since there is no longer any contrast.
[Icon w/ transparency lost in bad contrast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bPXU.png)
Is there a best practice when using transparent backgrounds on icons to make sure they maintain contrast and don't get lost in changing background images? Maybe a dithered or gradient transparency?

Comment: Could you provide an image of your icon and your background?